# Unit test configuration for multiple modules

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

In Android Studio, it's pretty easy to create a configuration which runs the unit tests for a particular module. But is there a way to create a configuration which runs the unit tests for *all* modules?

My particular project has multiple modules (a "main" module and a "library" module, say). I currently have two configurations: Main Unit Tests and Library Unit Tests. This works, but it'd be nice to just have Unit Tests run all my tests.

From the command line, this is trivial - just run ./gradlew testDebug and everything's happy. But I can't seem to figure it out from Android Studio. What am I missing here?

**Edit:** [cricket-007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) points out that the gradle command bar in Android Studio can let you run the testDebug command. This works, but isn't as full featured as a true configuration. So really, the question is how to create a configuration Unit Tests that runs all of the unit tests from all modules.

Comment: There is a Gradle command window on the right side of the IDE

Comment: Sure - that's a fair point. But that's not quite as nice as having a true configuration, for a couple of reasons. First, you have to know how to find the right task, and second, you can't easily do things like attach your debugger. It seems like there should be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that `testDebug` is in there. Wasn't that your question?

Comment: Not quite - the question is how to create the Unit Tests configuration that could run all tests instead of having to have two separate configurations. I'll try to clarify in the question, though.

Answer (score 9):

I've been able to make it work choosing "All in package" and search for tests across module dependencies. Because my App module dependes from all other modules, all the tests are run when running this Task.

[image: Configuration that worked for me]